# Swagger codegen downgrades gradle version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, swagger-codegen

I have created a gradle spring boot project in eclipse. Now I want to add a client generated by the swagger-codegen-cli.jar (version 3.0.20) that I put in the project.

After executing

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.yaml -l java --library resttemplate  > msg.txt
```

in powershell certain gradle files are overwritten. Most strikingly `gradle-wrapper.properties` changes the line

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4.1-bin.zip
```

to `.../gradle-2.6-bin.zip` and adds a timestamp from 2016?!

I also get the error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Could not fetch model of type 'EclipseProject' using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.6-bin.zip'.
Build file 'C:\Users\me\workspace\projectname\build.gradle' line: 2
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.3.1.RELEASE']
Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.springframework.boot']
Spring Boot plugin requires Gradle 5 (5.6.x only) or Gradle 6 (6.3 or later). The current version is Gradle 2.6 build.gradle    /demo   line 2  Gradle Error Marker
```

I've tried to change the version number back in `gradle-wrapper.properties`, but that alone doesn't seem to help. But grep didn't find any other occurrences of '2.6'
I would like to understand why the gradle version is changed and how to avoid that.

Comment: Is there a reason why you won't upgrade the OpenAPI generator? The current version will generate templates based on Gradle 6.0.1. Alternatively just add the files related to Gradle on the ignore list.

Comment: @LukasKörfer I am using *current stable*. I just tried the latest snapshot `swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.21-20200716.232045-68.jar` and it sets `../gradle-2.6-bin.zip` as well.

Comment: Ah sorry, I was talking about the OpenAPI Generator, a fork of Swagger CodeGen. I did not know that Swagger CodeGen still has new releases.

Answer (score 0):

Found that adding  `"additional-properties": {"ignoreFileOverride":"gradle-wrapper.properties"}` in `swagger-config.json` got our builds going for now.